# YesodAuth Google OAuth2 timing out

Tags: haskell, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, yesod

I'm trying to set up Authentication and Authorization for my Yesod website [according to the book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-and-authorization_authenticate_me).

However, once I set up my Google OAuth2, I get a timeout:

```
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "accounts.google.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
  path                 = "/o/oauth2/token"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "POST"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
  proxySecureMode      = ProxySecureWithConnect
}
 ConnectionTimeout
```

I tried using [`yesod-auth-oauth2` instead](https://pbrisbin.com/posts/googleemail2-deprecation/), but I still got a timeout error:

```
HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "www.googleapis.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),("Authorization","<REDACTED>"),("User-Agent","hoauth2"),("Accept","application/json")]
  path                 = "/oauth2/v3/token"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "POST"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 10
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
  proxySecureMode      = ProxySecureWithConnect
}
 ConnectionTimeout
```

I have the Google+ API and Contacts API enabled for the web application. I'm running my website locally right now, and have my Authorized redirect URIs as

- http://localhost:3000/auth/page/google/callback
- http://localhost:3000/auth/page/googleemail2/complete

Comment: Google+ was discontinued in 2015 I wonder how old that article is?

Comment: @DaImTo the API still seems active, and you can enable it in the Google OAuth console

Comment: I'm not so sure https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out for my case, it was due to the IPv6 address of `www.googleapis.com` being filtered out by Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter.

For instance, in the [`connection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/connection-0.3.1/docs/src/Network.Connection.html) package, I `Debug.Trace.trace`'d `addrs` in the `resolve'` function to find out that the server was trying to connect initially to the IPv6 address, then the IPv4 one. Connecting to the IPv4 addresses (e.g. using `ping` or `telnet`) worked, but the IPv6 address did not, so ultimately it was a firewall issue.